# GitLab kub agent : failing to get pods

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying kubernetes agent on gitlab.com

After following [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#register-the-agent-with-gitlab) to set it up and configure it as explain [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#update-your-gitlab-ciyml-file-to-run-kubectl-commands).
If I try the sample provided, I got some errors when trying to retrieve pods information

```bash
E0422 15:26:07.874822      21 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0422 15:26:07.875971      21 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0422 15:26:07.876827      21 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0422 15:26:07.879471      21 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0422 15:26:07.880885      21 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Weird stuff, is that running on the same project with the same agent an `helm` command works well and even weirder, if I run the same command in the `helm` job, it works -_-

```bash
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
yodamad-workshop-main-6f9f6b6cf6-qhkpm   1/1     Running   0          7h46m
```

Complete sources can be found in my [public project](https://gitlab.com/yodamad-workshops/kub-agent-workshop)

I've tried to open an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/407171) on it, no answer yet.

If someone has a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid "bug" : i used `kubectl config set-context` whereas i should have use `kubectl config use-context`

Switching to the correct one, everything works well